# How to write a memory manager that maps 4 GB for Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have an object that uses more than 2 gigabytes of virtual memory
But Delphi only managers 2 GB
I'm considering ether making a number of objects and grouping them and using the windows wow64 method some how and use 64 bit windows.
Or just upgrading memory manager to 4 GB and build it around Int64.
effectively I need TStream as the base object with Int64 used, instead of integers.

Comment: Now that all your old accounts have been merged into one, would you PLEASE use it? I.e. log in as "lexdean" and not create a new "lexdean" account every time?

Comment: Ach, don't know why didn't look at the date before editing - wish there were a way to effectively "undo" your edits....

Answer (score 14):

Lexdean, you're saying:

> effectively I need TStream as the base object with Int64 used, instead of integers

Well then, you're in luck (twice) because:

1. Delphi's TStream uses Int64 for position, it can access files much larger then 4Gb.
2. If a TStream interface is enough, you can write your own TStream to do whatever you want, you don't need to wait for an native 64bit Delphi compiler.

But if I were to answer the question in the title:

> How to write a memory manager that maps 4 giggs for Delphi

There's no way to do that with an 32bit compiler. Join the crowd of people asking for an 64 bit Delphi compiler!

Comment: http://delphi.uservoice.com/forums/4432-general/suggestions/143779-64-bit-support ;)

Comment: Now I think that x64 compiler isn't that great idea: now people would start allocating 4-6 Gbs of memory, without thinking about trying different approach...  :D

Answer (score 5):

Having a single 2 gigabyte object is not a good idea. If memory is fragmented you won't be able to allocate one even if the amount of free memory is enough. I would suggest that you try to use a list of smaller objects.

(I remember how in Turbo Pascal (the predecessor to Delphi) a variable couldn't be larger than 64 kilobyte... Oh, the times... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's no Delphi compiler as of yet that compiles 64-bit code.  You can get more out of your 32-bit address space if you put `{$SetPeFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}` in the DPR, though. It sets a flag in the PE header that lets Windows know it can allocate more than 2 GB of virtual memory to it.

Guffa's right, though.  If your object is trying to grab 2GB+ of contiguous memory, you're probably doing something wrong.  What are you trying to do?  Maybe there's a simpler way...

Comment: IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE requires also the /3GB Windows switch on 32 bit machines, or a 64 bit operating system.

Comment: alex has the answer
we have to investergte and not just think limitions/rules/law 

Lex Dean

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AWE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366527%28VS.85%29.aspx) APIs to obtain access to more memory in win32 apps. But you have to think *your* code around AWE rather than adapt AWE usage for your code. What I mean is that you can write a TAWEMemoryStream ... but it is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks alex you have the answer I need so bad
Thats the one
Thanks a lot

Lex Dean