# Delphi:- component will not register into the component tablet

Tags: delphi

I feel so stupid to not find this fault that most probably so simple.
Why I’m witting the component is TStringGrid dose not give access to selection in a OnSelectCell event. So I decided that its easer to call select cell near a OnDrawCell event with Invalidate, where I expect the selection property works and make a copy and give it a name GridSelection. Because my strings in each cell of my project do not get loner than sixty characters, I made a simple save and reload for my project.
To me this is not complicated but I just missed the mistake some how of why it will not register in the IDE’s component tablet under the ‘Standard’ tab. All I’m interested in is making it simple and it to work!!!!!!! I’m sure other eyes will see the mistake easily. Thanks in advance.

Lex Dean

```
unit StrGrid;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, StdCtrls, Grids;

type
  TSGrid = Class(TStringGrid)
  private
   FGridSelection: TGridRect;
   property Selection;
  public
   Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
   destructor Destroy; override;
   property GridSelection: TGridRect read FGridSelection;
   procedure Invalidate; override;
   Procedure SaveToFile(const FileName: string);
   Procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
  End;

procedure Register;

implementation

{ TSGrid }

constructor TSGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Inherited Create(AOwner);
  ColCount := 703;
  RowCount := 65536;
  DefaultRowHeight := 16;
  DefaultColWidth := 45;
  Options := [goFixedVertLine,goFixedHorzLine,goVertLine,
          goHorzLine, goRangeSelect, goThumbTracking, goAlwaysShowEditor];
end;

destructor TSGrid.Destroy;
begin
  Inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TSGrid.Invalidate;
begin
  FGridSelection := Selection;
  Inherited Invalidate;
end;

procedure TSGrid.LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
var Strs: TStrings;
    C, R, X: Integer;
    Str: String;
    N, S: byte;
begin
   Strs := TStringlist.Create;
   Strs.LoadFromFile(FileName);
   For X := 0 to Strs.Count -1 do
    Begin
     Str := Strs.Strings[X];
     N := 1;
     while Str[N] in['0'..'9'] do inc(N);
     C := StrToInt(Copy(Str, 1, n - 1));
     Inc(N);  S := N;
     while Str[N] in['0'..'9'] do inc(N);
     R := StrToInt(Copy(Str, S, n - 1));
     Cells[C, R] := Copy(Str, n + 1, Length(Str) - n - 1)
   End;
   Strs.Free;
end;

procedure TSGrid.SaveToFile(const FileName: string);
var Strs: TStrings;
    C, R: Integer;
begin
   Strs := TStringlist.Create;
   For C := 0 to ColCount -1 do
   For R := 0 to RowCount -1 do
     If length(Cells[C, R]) > 0 then
       Strs.Add(IntToStr(C) + ':' + IntToStr(R) + ';' + Cells[C, R]);
   Strs.SaveToFile(FileName);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
   RegisterComponents('Standard', [TSGrid]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: The issue is most likely not in the code. Have you deleted yout old *.dcu files and tried to install the component package again?

Comment: By the way: Is this your eleventh account here? You should *not* create a *new* account for each question.

Comment: @No - last time I counted he had fifteen accounts. Maybe it's the eleventh time somebody tells him to **use** existing accounts.

Comment: actually, it is his sixteenth http://stackoverflow.com/users/filter/lexdean, and that after a merged in the summer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191407

Comment: I can use this component easily in code and it works well
But it does not register into the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't cited using packages I assume that maybe the component wouldn't show up at design-time because it's not installed at all.
You have to create a design-time package, place the component inside it and install the package. Just defining Register won't work.

Try this:
http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/ss/newcomponentbpl.htm

God bless